# Error when trying to run reindent.py on line 71

Tags: python, windows

when trying to run the reindent command from the windows 10 command prompt, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\ianpo\renpy-7.3.5-sdk\projects\test\game>python -m reindent script.rpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ianpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\ianpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 154, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ianpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\reindent.py", line 71
    except getopt.error, msg:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any clues as to what is going on here would be very much appreciated. I am very new to Python and Windows, so please answer like I am a dummy. I have tried reinstalling with pip and making sure that I added an options flag. The seventh line down is causing the error.

```
def main():
    import getopt
    global verbose, recurse, dryrun, makebackup
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "drnvh",
                        ["dryrun", "recurse", "nobackup", "verbose", "help"])
    except getopt.error, msg:
        usage(msg)
        return
    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ('-d', '--dryrun'):
            dryrun += 1
        elif o in ('-r', '--recurse'):
            recurse += 1
        elif o in ('-n', '--nobackup'):
            makebackup = False
        elif o in ('-v', '--verbose'):
            verbose += 1
        elif o in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            return
    if not args:
        r = Reindenter(sys.stdin)
        r.run()
        r.write(sys.stdout)
        return
    for arg in args:
        check(arg)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on your issue with the code, but it looks like you have an error with your exception case:

```
 try:
   doSomething
 except getopt.error, msg:
   raise someError(debug)
```

The except statement is incorrect, needs to be something like this:

```
 except getopt as e:
   raise someError(msg)
```

If `getopt` is an `Exception` class you have made somewhere within this file then you will have to do it that way essentially.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was not clear. I am trying to run the reindent file from the python package of the same name. This error happens whenever I try to run 'python -m reindent ' from the windows command line, with or without a target file. I have tried reinstalling reindent and running it on several different files, all with the same results.

Comment: pls add more code to your question, specifically lines where the error occur.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem had to do with the fact that pip was installing an outdated version of reindent that was not compatible with current python. If anybody else is having the same problem, go [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/scripts/reindent.py) for the latest version of the file.

Comment: there is also a syntax error, that `pip` may have been one issue but you python doesn't allow that kind of syntax with `except` like that...has to be of format like `except KeyError as e` (as an example) something like what I have in my answer similar to the github script.

Comment: I am having the same issue, replaced the reindent.py file fron that link and worked. thank you